# Determine if variable is str in python2.7 or bytes in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that I want to be compatible with both Python2.7 and Python3.

For Python 2.7 - I want to do - `if isinstance(content, str)`.

For Python 3 - I want to do - `if isinstance(content, bytes)`.

Is there a way to do it in one line for both python versions?

P.S - we tried

```py
from six import string_types

if isinstance(content, string_types):
```

And it's not good here, because `isinstance(content, string_types)` returns `False` for `bytes` type.

Comment: What happens when you use `isinstance(content, bytes)` in Python 2?

Comment: *"`isinstance(content, string_types)` returns `False` for `bytes` type"* — **As you would expect.** `string_types` is `unicode` in Py2 and `str` in Py3. `binary_type` is `str` in Py2 and `bytes` in Py3.

Comment: `six.binary_type` is probably what you wanna use here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Binary type] is `str` in Python 2 and `bytes` in Python 3. Python 2.6 and 2.7 include `bytes` as a builtin alias of `str`, so six’s version is only necessary for Python 2.5 compatibility.
>
> https://six.readthedocs.io/#six.binary_type

What you actually want is to check for the *binary* type. And Python 2.7 already includes the `bytes` type, so you just need `isinstance(content, bytes)` which works on both Python 2.6+ and 3.